# Direct sum of modules, is there something like direct difference?

Tags: linear-algebra

This: $U_1 \bigoplus U_2 = V \Leftrightarrow U_1 = V - U_2$ is probably not true, but is there an alternative for writing this?

Comment: No, there's no such thing as “difference”. You can even have $U_1\oplus U_2\cong U_1\oplus U_3$ without having $U_2\cong U_3$.

Answer (score 3):

The trouble with this idea is that $U_1$ cannot be unique, since it is possible that $V = U_1\oplus U_2$ and $V = U_3\oplus U_2$. For example, take $V = \mathbb{R^2}$, and note that $V = span((1,0)) \oplus span((0,1)) = span((1,0))\oplus span((1,1))$.

Answer (score 1):

The kernel of a map is loosely analogous to subtraction.

If $f : X \oplus Y \to Y$ is the projection map, then $X$ (along with the insertion map $X \to X \oplus Y$) is the kernel of $f$.

I suppose cokernel is just as good of an analogy.